# How can I get the body to continue look the same when a div inside overflows to the right?

Tags: css

```
html {
background-color: #e2e2e2;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;   
white-space:nowrap;

}

body {
background-color: #fff;
border-top: solid 10px #000;
color: #333;
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;       
}

#body {
min-width:1015px;  
background-color: #efeeef;
padding-bottom: 35px;       
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

I have css above in a page of mine. The #body is used for a div that's getting populated by partial views using ajax.

The problem is that when content in #body is overflowing to the right then body does not encapsulate the content of #body, it stays the size of the window when loaded. So when scrolling horizontally the background looks different for the body part in the region that becomes visible when scrolling.

How can i get the body to continue look the same when #body owerflows to the right?

http://jsfiddle.net/q2j4wcmo/

**UPDATE:**

Hashem Qolami did solve part of my problem, when zooming in on the content in #body, body still incapsulates #body and it looks as it supposed to. But in my solution when loading the page and the content in #body is overflowing body is not encapsulating the content in #body.

Any idea what could be different when running in jsfiddler where it's obviously working as supposed to?

**UPDATE 2:**
new example

http://jsfiddle.net/q2j4wcmo/10/

Comment: apply `min-width:1015px;` to `<body>` as well. http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/q2j4wcmo/1/

Comment: Or just remove `inline-block` from `#body`.

Comment: `Any idea what could be different...` Unfortunately, No, until you update the fiddle with a simplified version of the original markups. None of us can guess and/or imagine a dozen of possibilities which may cause the issue.

Comment: I have posted a new fiddle, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is changing display type of the `<body>` to `inline-block` to let it grow horizontally by its contents.

Also you could use `min-width: 100%;` to make sure that the `<body>` always fills the entire page even if its content is not that wide:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/q2j4wcmo/3/)**

```css
html {
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

**Note:** Since a percentage value of `min-width` refers to the width of the containing block, you have to specify an explicit width of `<html>` element as well (as I did).

Comment: @asdfasdf In fact there's nothing to do with `<body>` itself. The issue belongs to the floated links within the light-gray section which their widths exceeds the width of `#body` element.

Comment: @asdfasdf That being said, you could either increase minimum width of `#body` to `1117px;` (`(50px + 5px margin-left) + 9 * 118px = 1117px`) **[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/q2j4wcmo/13/)** OR display the links as `inline-block` like so: **[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/q2j4wcmo/14/)**.

Comment: Thanks! Again it did not work in my real solution. If you explain to me the second solution, with inline-block, what it's actually doing i might be able to change it to fit the real solution.

Comment: @asdfasdf Unlike CSS floats, displaying elements as `inline-element`s won't remove them from document normal flow, i.e. they'll act as "words in a text" which stay beside each other and be separated by a white space. Hence by the use of [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) we can prevent line breaks in order to keep them in one line no matter how much they are. Using this method prevents text wrapping and [stretches the container](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/q2j4wcmo/15/) to be wide enough to encapsulate the children.

Comment: Thanks! I meant the second solution you offered in fiddler. Could you please explain how following css from your fiddler solution works: #body div:nth-child(3) > div ? In #body it looks for two layers of div, that means <div style="margin-left: 0px;"> and second div: <div style="float:left;width:118px;"> but after that there are no more div so how does > div work ? How does it solve the problem ? Does table count as a div? I dont get it.

Comment: @asdfasdf Ah... I just used that selector to remove float property of `<div style="float:left;width:118px;">` elements and adding `display: inline-block` declaration instead of editing the HTML section to remove inline styles; I am such a lazy person :) If you're happy with inline styles go with it.

Comment: @asdfasdf Actually in `#body` there are 5 `div` element, the first one is `#progressbar`, the second one is `<div style="margin-left:60px;">` and the third one: `<div style="margin-left: 0px;">`. By using `#body div:nth-child(3) > div` it targets all `<div>` children of the third `<div>` (child) element inside the `#body`.